# rCharts and Shiny - plot does not show up

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, shiny-server

So I am trying to build a Shiny app with rCharts. When I run the following code (below) I get no errors and the sidebar panel scrollbar shows, but the barplot itself is not generated. (It works fine if I just run the nPlot() function from R Studio).

## server.R:

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
# random data:
smpl<-data.frame(gene = c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5",
                          "gene6","gene7","gene8","gene9","gene10"),
                 direction = c("up","down","up","up","up",
                               "up","up","down","down","down"),
                 type = c("norm","norm","tum","tum","norm",
                          "tum","tum","norm","tum","tum"),
                 foldChange = c(1.3, 0.4, 1.3, 3.0, 1.6,
                                2.9, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    n <- subset(smpl, type == input$x)
    p1 <- nPlot(foldChange ~ gene, group = "direction", n, 
          type = 'multiBarChart')

    p1$set(dom = 'myChart')
    return(p1)
  })
})
```

## ui.R

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Sample Bar Plot"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",         
                label = "Select:",
                choices = c("norm","tum"),
                selected = "norm")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "polycharts")
  )
))
```

Ive tried using both 'renderChart' with the 'pt$set(dom = myChart)' line, and 'renderChart2' with AND without the 'pt$set(dom = myChart)' line, but neither option works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are linking to an incorrect library. `nPlot` is `nvd3` rather then `polychart`:

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
smpl<-data.frame(gene = c("gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5",
                          "gene6","gene7","gene8","gene9","gene10"),
                 direction = c("up","down","up","up","up",
                               "up","up","down","down","down"),
                 type = c("norm","norm","tum","tum","norm",
                          "tum","tum","norm","tum","tum"),
                 foldChange = c(1.3, 0.4, 1.3, 3.0, 1.6,
                                2.9, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6))
runApp(
  list(server= function(input, output) {
    output$myChart <- renderChart2({
      n <- subset(smpl, type == input$x)
      p1 <- nPlot(foldChange ~ gene, group = "direction", n, 
                  type = 'multiBarChart')

#      p1$set(dom = 'myChart')
      return(p1)
    })
  }
  , ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Sample Bar Plot"),

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "x",         
                  label = "Select:",
                  choices = c("norm","tum"),
                  selected = "norm")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      showOutput("myChart", "nvd3")
    )
  )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Happy to help. Easy mistake to make.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I changed the renderChart to renderChart2 and it works for me.

Comment: @黄小立 yes. this should be in the docs somewhere. was following the below tutorial and spent an hour re-checking before realizing the tutorial is wrong and renderChart doesn't appear to work (but renderChart2 does). http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsShiny/